# Test error lower than training error

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, genetic-programming

Would appreciate your input on this. I am constructing a regression model with the help of genetic programming.

If my RMSE on test data is (much) lower than my RMSE on training data for a 1:5 ratio of data, should I be worried?

The test data is drawn randomly without replacement from a set of 24 data points. The model was built using genetic programming technique so the number of features, modeling framework etc vary as I minimize the training RMSE regularized by the number of nodes in the GP tree.

Is the model underfitted? Or should I have minimized MSE instead of RMSE (I thought it would be the same as MSE is positive and the minimum of MSE would coincide with the minimum of RMSE assuming the optimizer is good enough to find the minimum)?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

So your model is trained on 20 out of 24 data points and tested on the 4 remaining data points?

To me it sounds like you need (much) more data, so you can have a larger train and test sets. I'm not surprised by the low performance on your test set as it seems that your model wasn't able to learn from such few data. As a rule of thumb, for machine learning you can never have enough data. Is it a possibility to gather a larger dataset?

Comment: you're right in suspecting it is not possible to gather a larger dataset. The performance on test set is actually very good >.<, much better than on training set. I tried to do a 6 fold cross validation. The average test error is still very low (RMSE). In terms of MAPE, the test performance is also very good (less than 2 %). Training error is larger, could be three orders of magnitude larger and more. In RMSE and MAPE!

Comment: Aah I misread it, I thought your test was performing bad. This is an interesting situation indeed then. Is your performance on the training data an average of the whole training period or only the performance as measured once the model has finished learning?

Comment: hi Sicco,the training performance is once the model has finished learning.

Comment: Well, then I'm baffled :D. I would be inclined to say that something is wrong. Either the test result is pure coincidence (have you tried multiple tests and different ratios of train/test data?) or I guess that something might have gone wrong in the implementation. Getting better results on the test set than on train set shouldn't occur :D

Comment: i have rechecked with multiple tests and different ratios. with multiple tests, the RMSE and MAPE behavior remain as described about 90% of the time. with different ratios, i.e. 50-50,  the training error would be lower than test, quite consistently. i'm quite baffled as well and quite suspicious something is not quite right =)

Comment: finally got what was wrong. there was something not quite right with the testing =). i computed the weights of the ensemble using linear least squares on the test data itself >.<. now the thing is behaving as expected.